Не подключается библиотека unity.UI
Проблема: не видит библиотеку  Unity.UI после того, как я обновил visual studio installer и саму visual studio (давно не обновлял), до этого все было хорошо. 
Способы решения, которые применил :

проверил в Unity, что в preferences-> external tools стоит Visual Studio
еще раз проверил, что в Visual Studio стоит дополнение от Unity
Причем сама unity работает исправно, в консоли unity ошибок не выдает, все штатно

Пока VS2019 не удалял и не переустанавливал, надеюсь, что не придется.
Буду очень благодарен!)

проблема решена - нужно убрать галочку напротив built-in packages:

